# Setting background with previously loaded picture

Tags: javascript, background

This is piece of my JavaScript code:

```
images.pic = new Image();
images.pic.src = 'http://.../somepic.png';
```

How to set background in DIV using picture previously loaded and stored in `images.pic`? This below doesn't work:

```
 somediv=document.createElement("div");
 somediv.style.backgroundImage=images.pic;
```

Comment: Just load it regularly both times. The browser will take care of not downloading the same picture again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
somediv.style.backgroundImage="url(" + images.pic.src + ")";
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKZQR/